# Dynamically loaded javascript not executing

Tags: javascript, dynamic

For my debugging, I'm trying to load a javascript file from the console.  I've tried several options:

```
var ns = document.createElement("script");
ns.type = 'text/javascript';
ns.src = 'http://localhost/test.js';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ns);
```

and also:

```
$.getScript('http://localhost/test.js');
```

Neither worked as expected.  I can see the `<script>` tag added in the DOM tree but the script is not execute and the *Network* tab in the developer's tools does not show the script being loaded.

How can I get it to execute?

**UPDATE:** Interestingly, the code works fine on Chrome, but not on FireFox (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Is the script test.js really accessible from http://localhost/test.js when you browse the url directly?
In most cases you want to have in "src" a relative path to the script.

Comment: @joewhite86 Yes, it's accessible.  I can't have a relative path, because the main loaded page is from the remove server - but the script I need to load is from my local machine.

Comment: I can confirm that the code you posted is working for http (not https), can you provide your test.js code and what you'd expect to see?

Comment: it's working on ubuntu 14.04 but it say "Reload the page to get source for: test.js"

Comment: Try adding it to the body. BTW, you can say `document.body`, no need for `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`.